# AWS Batch Jobs does not scale to maximum Vcpus

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, cloud, aws-batch

I'm trying to run a webscraper with 200 VCPUs on an AWS Queue( **queue A**), but it's only using 40 even if the maximum and desired number of VCPUs is 200. What should I do ?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, we figured out that the issue was with my AWS account itself. So I had to contact AWS team and ask them to increase the maximum number of VCPUs